# Gradle doesnt build and cant see the activity_main.xml

Tags: java, android, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I have been working on a project for college but I can not do on my own pc first was the sdk now the gradel doesn't build...Any help?

I already tried to clear the cache and nothing workked... can it be something with the sdk? I was not avalable to install the sdk beacuse it said it was already installed so I copy the sdk from another pc
[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmOFJ.png)

Comment: Try with Android Studio.

Comment: Why did you stop the Gradle build? Wait until it finishes, and Gradle will download all needed SDKs and libraries.